# Command to print subtitle

Tags: titles

I’m using TeXLive 2015 and the `scrreprt` document class.

Is there a command like `\thesubtitle` to print the subtitle as defined by `\subtitle{…}`? I get an ‘undefined control sequence’ error on `\thesubtitle` when compiling the following (either with lualatex or pdflatex).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\title{T}
\subtitle{S}

\begin{document}
\thetitle, \thesubtitle
\end{document}
```

Here, `\thetitle` works as expected. Do I need to load a package to get `\thesubtitle`? Is there another command to do this?

(Can’t be the first one to run into this problem, but I couldn’t find anything in the last five minutes on the web.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "content" of `\title` and `\subtitle` is stored in the "internal" commands `\@title` and `\@subtitle`. To use them (not using `\maketitle` or similar command) in the document, you have to use `\makeatletter` (and `\makeatother`)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter\@title, \@subtitle\makeatother
\end{document}
```